# inserting text in a gulp stream

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to hard-code a variable into a GULP task (for development purposes and not production), I need something like this:

```
gulp.task('buildJS', function() {
    gulp.insert('var DEV = true;')  // inserting the text somehow
        .src([
            './js/a.js',
            './js/b.js',
            './js/c.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

I tried to google it, but I get a bunch of bad results, also not sure what exactly to look for here, but can only describe here.

As you can see in the first line, I would like to insert some *variable* that comes **before** all other things (in this specific case, and then the rest of the files should be included, and it all gets concatenated into one file at the end, but I am not sure how to do that... Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Are you trying to set an environment variable, or do you want to set a global variable used in your production JS output? You could use [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) and prepend a small file containing your declaration to your `.src()` stack

Comment: I want to add an actual JS variable that the browser could use. I really want to **avoid** creating any files to add, since that would be an ugly solution to the problem, instead of doing it directly from gulp, where I think it should be done, automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[gulp-header](https://github.com/godaddy/gulp-header)** plugin that allow to append text at the beginning of your files and which support templating.

You can do something like :

```
var header = require('gulp-header');

gulp.task('buildJS', function() {
  gulp.src([
      './js/a.js',
      './js/b.js',
      './js/c.js'
    ])
    .pipe(header('var DEV = true;'))
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

Or if you only want to append it on the concatened file

```
gulp.task('buildJS', function() {
  gulp.src([
      './js/a.js',
      './js/b.js',
      './js/c.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(header('var DEV = true;'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

Comment: would it not be included in the saved file if I do it like the first example? in that case it makes no sense to even use it that way..

Comment: I don't really understand your needs, if you do the first example, you will have 3 occurrences of the `var DEV = true` in the output file, and nothing will be written in sources, if you do the second, you will only have one header at the top of your file.

Comment: ha excellent than sir! of course the second example is the proffered one! who want's the same line 3 times in the code...

Comment: Yeah I know, that was just an example, glad that helped ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use gulp-header : https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-header

In your case, put it after the concat operation in the pipeline.